# BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81: Method defaults does not exist

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I'm getting `BadMethodCallException` on setting default parameters of a url from a middleware according to documentation [Setting Default Url Values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#default-values).

[image: Bad Method Exception]

Here is my code

Class SetDefaultLocaleForUrls

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class SetDefaultLocaleForUrls
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $locale = $request->route()->parameter('locale');
        $site_locales = ['en','es','fr','de','zh','tw','nl','pt'];

        if(!empty($locale) && !in_array($locale,$site_locales)){
            $locale = 'en';
        }

        if (empty($locale)) {
            $locale = 'en';  //default locale
        }

        if (empty($locale)) {
            $locale = 'en';  //default locale
        }

        URL::defaults(['locale' => $locale]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My route configuration

```
Route::get('/{locale?}/about-us', ['as' => 'frontend.about-us.localized', 'uses' => 'Frontend\AboutUsController@index'])->middleware('locale');
```

My Middleware configuration in protected $routeMiddleware

```
'locale' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetDefaultLocaleForUrls::class,
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Double check the **namespace** and **use** statements in your route middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class SetDefaultLocaleForUrls
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        URL::defaults(['locale' => $request->user()->locale]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

### Update:

I've put your code in to an instance of Laravel and I don't get any errors.  PHPStorm reports `Method 'defaults' not found in \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL` but it doesn't result in a BadMethodCallException so I think that is something with my PHPStorm configuration only.

In `SetDefaultLocaleForUrls` class I added

```
app()->setLocale($locale);
```

This worked correctly with regards to displaying data in my view according to the URL I entered.  This was using a check in my view, for example:

```
@if (App::isLocale('de'))
    <h1>Guten Morgen</h1>
@else
    <h1>Good Morning</h1>
@endif
```

However, if I entered a URL not in your `$site_locales` array, it did not update the URL as I would have expected.  However, it does set the Locale to your default `en` and display the correct data in the view.

Is the method intended to rewrite the URL?

One thing you could try in relation to the BadMethodCallException is to clear your route cache:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: Can you please post file where you are seting defaults

Comment: Yes, Please wait while I am updating my answer

Comment: Remove the ? from the route.  Should just be {locale}

Comment: not working, I tried this also, However its an optional parameter, the main problem is with URL::defaults(['locale'=>$locale]); command

Comment: How about changing your variable `$locale` to `$set_locale` (for example)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156615/discussion-between-rajat-jain-and-kerrin).